# ERROR WHEN IMPORTING PYTORCH (The filename or extension is too long)

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, torch, huggingface-transformers

I'm using Anconda to run my Transformers project locally in google colab.

I've created a new environment (tf_gpu) and installed (supposedly) everything I need.

And everything works fine, but when I try to simply import pytorch, this error appears:

```
[WinError 206] The filename or extension is too long: 'C:\\Users\\34662\\anaconda3\\envs\\tf_gpu\\lib\\site-packages\\torch\\lib'
```

When clearly the path is not long enough to trigger this error.

My python version is 3.8, and my GPU is a Nvidia GeForce GTX 1650, so it shouldn't be a GPU problem

Does anybody knows why this happens?

Any help is good at this point, I don't know how to solve this.

[Here I leave a screenshot of the complete error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbQ3n.png)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: python version ?

Comment: Python version is 3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the error ist not a too long path error it is a file not found error which mean that pytorch is not correctly installed

Comment: Basically I had to remove conda and any cuda element from my computer and reinstall again, It was basically a incorrect instalation (version mismatch)

Comment: nice to hear that you where able to fix it